# If we use java config for obj creation and other things is it not against IOC principle

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

when we use java config for meta-data config it is against IOC principle, we make use of new keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new keyword for a dependency is used in the config class.  The IOC principle still applies as long as managed spring beans have their dependencies supplied/injected by the spring container.

For example you can still reap the benefits of IOC like injecting mocks for dependencies for unit tests.

Plus you get added benefits using Java config like type safety and easier refactoring.

Comment: Hi chrud, thanks for ur reply, when i use new keyword how does spring manage the beans?? Later i want i can use but the objects we created are using new keyword nly right

Comment: Instead of manually creating in java config, you can also use `@Component` on the spring bean and `@CopmonentScan` to scan a package for spring beans.  Once a spring managed bean is configured, it can be injected into another spring bean with `@Autowired`.  More details here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Comment: I know that buddy, but my question is all about java config, is it means IOC is not there? hope u get my qn now. my qn is not about xml config or annotation, only abt java config

Comment: If you add an example that would help.   IOC is still met with Java config.  Your depending on an interface and implementation is injected at runtime, right?

Comment: simple if i use new keyword to create a object in spring who creates the object? Spring container? IOC is object will be created by container not programmer writing as new className() right?

Comment: It sounds like you're creating an object in code, and not having spring manage it at all.  But without an example it's hard to tell.  Spring container will only create the instance if it is spring managed - like by using `@Component`, `@Autowired`

Comment: sorry to say...have u seen code in java config? why do you still ask example buddy.its all over net. its simple spring5 or spring boot has java config, if i dont use @component also it works, i ll give u a link @Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {
   `@Bean 
   public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
      return new HelloWorld();
   }
}

Comment: In your example, add where the spring bean helloWorld is injected.

Comment: public class App {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
            ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
     HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloBean");
     
     obj.printHelloWorld("Spring3 Java Config");

 }
}

Comment: Pls do not waste my time...i know the answer almost but just needed to confirm...just 2% of doubt...This very basic spring concept IOC...